# Dropdown menu not anchored below field

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

I've the following, very basic code:

```html
<select id="dir">
        <option value="N">N</option>
        <option value="S">S</option>
        <option value="E">E</option>
        <option value="W">W</option>
</select>
```

My system displays HTML using IE. In the displayed page:

- On loading the page, the initial value displayed in the field is **N**.
- I click the field. The dropdown menu appears with the **N** option hovering over the field. The **S**, **E** & **W** options are **below** the field.
- I click S. The dropdown menu disappears, and the value displayed in the field is now **S**.
- I click the field again. The dropdown menu appears with the **S** option hovering over the field. The **N** option is **above** the field, while the **E** & **W** options remain **below** the field.

This is not how I expected dropdown menus to display. How do I change the code such that the entire dropdown menu is **below** the field whenever it's displayed, neither partially hovering over the field nor above it?

Comment: Not sure why I can't edit my question. Anyway, I can only use the technologies tagged. No jquery or other third party stuff, please

Answer (score 0):

This is the normal behaviour of a dropdown select.

If you want it otherwise you'd have to either build it yourself in javascript/jquery or look for a jquery plugin.

You'd have to remove the select options above the selected one and add them afterwards again. You could use the onchange handler for that.

As said - this is the normal behaviour, even though it isn't expected by you.

Comment: Ok, so maybe I didn't know that's normal, but dropdown menus I've seen virtually everywhere I interacted with one on the Internet keeps the entire menu anchored below the field. So can you answer how I can get that, please?

Comment: Could you link me to like... one of those dropdowns on a website? Also I did answer - you would have to recreate the list with the options after the selected and fill the dropdown again. You can use the onchange callback for that.